# Rendering video object with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to render a video object inside a videoList array with vuejs. The video is being pushed inside the array but the view only outputs "[object HTMLVideoElement]". How do I get vue to render the video ?

```
<div v-for="(video,index) in videoList" :key="index">
    {{video}}
</div>

export default {
data(){
    return{
        videoList:[]
    }
},
methods:{
    connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
        const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream)
        const video = document.createElement('video')
        call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
            this.addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
        })
    },
    addVideoStream(video, stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream
        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
            video.play()
        })
        this.videoList.push(video)
    }
 },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the `{{ }}` notation takes whatever you put inside, evaluates it as JavaScript expression and displays the result as string.

Which means that if you create `<video>` elements in controller and place them in the template between moustaches you'll get: `[object HTMLVideoElement]`.

First and foremost, you shouldn't be creating DOM elements inside the controller. Let Vue render for you and use the created DOM elements via [$refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs).

Before I could provide an actual example you'll need to update your question with more info about what's triggering the `<video>` elements generation. Ideally, you should turn it into a *runnable* snippet.

In principle, your `videoList` should be an array of objects holding the necessary data for your `<video>` elements to function (not actual DOM `<video>` elements). Once one such object has been pushed to the array, Vue will render a `<video>` tag for it if you use something along these lines:

```
<video v-for="(video,index) in videoList" :key="index" ref="videos" />
```

In your `addVideoStream` method you'll be pushing an object to the `videoList` array and, inside a `$nextTick()` wrapper (to allow Vue time to generate the `<video>` tag), you'll be able to target the `<video>` tag using `this.$refs.videos[n]` (0 based) and interact with it (add listeners, change attributes, play, pause, etc...).

In short, this should work:

```
methods: {
  connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
    const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream);
    call.on('stream', uStream => this.addVideoStream(uStream));
  },
  addVideoStream(stream) {
    this.videoList.push({});
    this.$nextTick().then(() => {
      const video = this.$refs.videos[this.videoList.length - 1];
      if (!video) return;
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
        video.play();
      })
    })
  }
}
```

If it doesn't work, you might want to provide a minimal runnable example, so I could test it hands on and see what's wrong.